# How do I add values from two different tables using a MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables, `People` and `Shifts`. I want to write a trigger that takes entries in `Shifts` and updates the values in `People` by adding a value from the `Shifts.Shift` column to the `Coordinates` column in `People`. However, my code seems to affect every entry under `People` the same way. I'll illustrate below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE People(
`id` INT,
`Name` VARCHAR(10),
`Coordinates` INT);

CREATE TABLE Shifts(
`id` INT,
`Name` VARCHAR(10),
`Shift` INT);

INSERT INTO People VALUES (1,"Ashley",28),(2,"Bob",101),(3,"Curtis",31),(4,"Daniel",69),(5,"Esther",3);

CREATE TRIGGER Shifting_Location
AFTER INSERT ON Shifts
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE People
SET `id` = NEW.`id`,
    `Name` = NEW.`Name`,
    `Coordinates` = `Coordinates` + NEW.`Shift`;
```

Here are the tables:

***People***

| id | Name | Coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashley | 28 |
| 2 | Bob | 101 |
| 3 | Curtis | 31 |
| 4 | Daniel | 69 |
| 5 | Esther | 3 |

***Shifts*** (empty at first)

| id | Name | Shift |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

Now if I insert a record into `Shifts` like so:

```sql
INSERT INTO Shifts VALUES (1, "Ashley", 12)
```

I want to get

| id | Name | Coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashley | **40** |
| 2 | Bob | 101 |
| 3 | Curtis | 31 |
| 4 | Daniel | 69 |
| 5 | Esther | 3 |

| id | Name | Shift |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ashley | 12 |

Where the **28** next to Ashley had **12** added to it and is now **40**.

However, what I get instead is:

| id | Name | Coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Ashley** | **40** |
| **1** | **Ashley** | **113** |
| **1** | **Ashley** | **43** |
| **1** | **Ashley** | **81** |
| **1** | **Ashley** | **15** |

The `(1, "Ashley")` has overwritten all the other record entries, and all the values in coordinates had 12 added to them instead of just the first row. Again, here is the trigger I wrote to achieve this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Shifting_Location
AFTER INSERT ON Shifts
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE People
SET `id` = NEW.`id`,
    `Name` = NEW.`Name`,
    `Coordinates` = `Coordinates` + NEW.`Shift`;
```

Comment: Your update statement does not have a where clause, therefore it affects all rows in the people table. Btw, you should not store the name in the shifts table, you should store the id of the people there and use that information in the where clause.

Comment: @Shadow I tried adding `WHERE People.id= Shifts.id;`, but I got an Error 1054: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Shifts.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Not shifts id, it's NEW.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Shifting_Location
AFTER INSERT ON Shifts
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE People
SET Coordinates = Coordinates + NEW.Shift
WHERE id = New.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/WrUsqQnH